# assigning value of one class's instance variable in another class

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

I am trying to assign value of FileData's instance variable in File class

At first FileData's nextIndex should **all** be -1, and then it should be assigned the value of counter
I've tried get,set and FileData array to assign value but its not working and
gives NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
**I've tried:**

```
class FileData
{
   int nextIndex = 0;    
   public void setIndex()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
           nextIndex = -1;
        }
    }
 }

class File
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       FileData[] FD = new FileData[10];
       for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
       {
           FD[i].nextIndex = i;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You have an array of FileData type, but no FileData in it

Comment: thank u,    when im trying to print the  FDarray[i]   it its showing this ------------------  JavaApplication129.FileData@55f96302       ----------- how to make it print the data entered. ive tried--------------------------for(int i=0; i<counter;i++) { FDarray[i].nextIndex = i; System.out.println(FDarray[i] + " "+ FDarray[i].nextIndex); }

Comment: @aksappy pls see ^

Answer (score 2):

When working with objects, you first have to create an instance. All I've done is add a declarator in the loop and formatted the code:

```java
class FileData {
    int nextIndex = 0;

    public void setIndex() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            nextIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}

class File {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileData[] FD = new FileData[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            FD[i] = new FileData();
            FD[i].nextIndex = i;
        }

    }

}
```

Note that the `FileData[] FD = new FileData[10];` bit just declares an array of the type FileData, and does not yet give each object its needed storage space.

Answer (score 1):

The array elements here are null:

```
FileData[] FD = new FileData[10];
```

First you need to create the objects:

```
for(int i=0; i < FD.length ;i++)
{    
     FD[i] = new FileData();
     FD[i].nextIndex = i;
}
```

Comment: im trying this for prinitng, but its printing this
JavaApplication129.FileData@55f96302 for FDarray[i] how do i make it print the data ive entered

for(int i=0; i<counter;i++)
        {
          FDarray[i].nextIndex = i;
          System.out.println(FDarray[i] + " "+ FDarray[i].nextIndex);
        }

Comment: pls see this ^^ @encho solakov

Comment: you could override toString method for FDarray class:
public String toString() { 
        return .....
    }